# Python Takuzu solver

Tags: python, performance, sudoku

If you are unfamiliar with the logic puzzle game Takuzu, I learned how to play it and was inspired to make the project from [this challenge posted on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/3pwf17/20151023_challenge_237_hard_takuzu_solver/). The short version of the game is it's a logic puzzle that uses 0s and 1s on an n×n grid that does not allow three repeating numbers in a row nor two rows or columns to be the same.

I would love to get advice on style, variable naming, and areas where efficiency could be improved if possible. One function in particular I would like advice on is `build_perms`. It's functional and yields the results I want, however it does so with multi-layered nested lists. I'd also like to know if I went overkill with list comprehensions. I haven't extensively used them in the past, so I thought this may be a good way to learn. Either way, here's the project:

```
import re, itertools, copy

def rotate_right(puzzle):
    """
    Rotates the puzzle right thus making
    our columns into our rows and vice versa
    """
    return [''.join(t) for t in zip(*puzzle[::-1])]

def rotate_left(puzzle):
    """
    Rotates the puzzle left thus making
    our rows back into our columns
    """
    return [''.join(t) for t in list(zip(*puzzle))[::-1]]

def replace_twos(line):
    """
    An easy placement of alternating numbers. 
    Helps fill out the initial board
    """
    line = line.replace('.00.', '1001')
    line = line.replace('00.', '001')
    line = line.replace('.00', '100')

    line = line.replace('.11.', '0110')
    line = line.replace('11.', '110')
    line = line.replace('.11', '011')

    line = line.replace('1.1', '101')
    line = line.replace('0.0', '010')

    return line

def half_filled(line):
    """
    Fills all .s with the opposite number
    if the board has half already filled
    """
    if line.count('1') == (len(line) // 2):
        line = line.replace('.', '0')
    elif line.count('0') == (len(line) // 2):
        line = line.replace('.', '1')

    return line

def solve_partial(puzzle):
    """
    Finds rows and columns that match a 
    criteria and replaces them 
    """
    for i in range(len(puzzle)):
        puzzle[i] = replace_twos(puzzle[i])
        puzzle[i] = half_filled(puzzle[i])

    rot_puzzle = rotate_right(puzzle)
    for i in range(len(rot_puzzle)):
        rot_puzzle[i] = replace_twos(rot_puzzle[i])
        rot_puzzle[i] = half_filled(rot_puzzle[i])

    puzzle = rotate_left(rot_puzzle)

    return puzzle

def fill_rest(puzzle, valid_lines):
    """
    Brute force solves the rest of the
    puzzle by populating potential 
    solutions for each line and validating
    whether the entire puzzle is valid
    """
    # In the unlikely scenario where we've already solved it
    if satisfy_constraints(puzzle):
        return puzzle

    line_solutions = []
    for i in range(len(puzzle)):
        sol = set()
        for line in valid_lines:
            if like_original(puzzle[i], line):
                sol.add(line)
        line_solutions.append(list(sol))

    filled_puzzles = list(itertools.product(*line_solutions))

    for p in filled_puzzles:
        if satisfy_constraints(p):
            return p

    print("UH OH")

def satisfy_constraints(puzzle):
    """
    Checks a bunch of criteria the puzzle must
    match before it satisfies the constraints.
    """
    rot_puzzle = rotate_right(puzzle)

    contain_dot = not any(['.' in line for line in puzzle])
    reg_eq = all([equal_num(line) for line in puzzle])
    rot_eq = all([equal_num(line) for line in rot_puzzle])

    # Make sure all of the rows/columns are unique
    reg_diff = [puzzle.count(line) for line in puzzle] == [1]*len(puzzle)
    rot_diff = [rot_puzzle.count(line) for line in rot_puzzle] == [1]*len(puzzle)

    # If any of them have three consecutive
    reg_consecutive = not any([three_consecutive(line) for line in puzzle])
    rot_consecutive = not any([three_consecutive(line) for line in rot_puzzle])

    return all([contain_dot, reg_eq, rot_eq, reg_diff, rot_diff, reg_consecutive, rot_consecutive])

def like_original(line, potential_solution):
    # Our line is already in the form of a regular
    # expression. '.' is a wildcard 
    return True if re.match(line, potential_solution) else False

def three_consecutive(line):
    """
    Returns a bool whether or not there are three
    consecutive numbers in a row on our line
    """
    return True if re.search('[0]{3,}|[1]{3,}', line) else False

def equal_num(line):
    """
    Returns a bool determining if there are more
    1s than half the length of our line
    """
    if line.count('1') > len(line) // 2 or line.count('0') > len(line) // 2:
        return False
    return True

def flatten(deep_list):
    while type(deep_list[0]) == type([]):
        deep_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(deep_list))

    return deep_list

def build_perms(s, match, left):
    """
    A recursive function that takes an original 
    prefix, a dictionary that matches with the
    prefix, and the number of iterations we have
    left. Returns all the permutations for a prefix.
    """
    if left == 0:
        return s[:-2] # Cut off our last two appended 
    prefix = s[-2:]
    return [build_perms(s + postfix, match, left - 2) for postfix in match[prefix]]

def get_permutations(size):
    # A dictionary to match all of our valid 
    # prefixes with all valid postfixes
    match = {
        '00': ['10', '11'],
        '01': ['01', '10', '00'],
        '10': ['01', '10', '11'],
        '11': ['00', '01']
    }

    perms = [build_perms(key, match, size) for key in match]
    perms = list(set(flatten(perms)))
    return list(filter(equal_num, perms))

def print_puzzle(puzzle):
    for line in puzzle:
        print(line)
    print("")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    puzzle = open('puzzle.txt', 'r').readlines()
    puzzle = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in puzzle]

    print("ORIGINAL")
    print_puzzle(puzzle)

    puzzle_copy = []
    # Go until our solve partial returns the
    # same puzzle as before; this means we
    # can't get any more easy placements
    while puzzle != puzzle_copy:
        puzzle_copy = copy.deepcopy(puzzle)
        puzzle = solve_partial(puzzle)

    print("AFTER PARTIAL")
    print_puzzle(puzzle)

    valid_lines = get_permutations(len(puzzle))
    puzzle = fill_rest(puzzle, valid_lines)

    print("AFTER FILL")
    print_puzzle(puzzle)
```

Below are some inputs to test the program on. The 12×12 puzzle takes especially long.

```
110...
1...0.
..0...
11..10
....0.
......

0....11..0..
...1...0....
.0....1...00
1..1..11...1
.........1..
0.0...1.....
....0.......
....01.0....
..00..0.0..0
.....1....1.
10.0........
..1....1..00
```

Comment: `reg_diff = [puzzle.count(line) for line in puzzle] == [1]*len(puzzle)` runs in quadratic time. I cannot benchmark to verify that this is your bottleneck (hence this is not an answer), but I suggest using `Counter` for linear runtime anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the input! I just tried some benchmarks using time.clock() on a Linux system. Checking a 12x12 puzzle and my original method: `[puzzle.count(line) for line in puzzle] == [1]*len(puzzle)` I clocked at `5.499e-06`. Trying Counter doing `collections.Counter(puzzle).values() == [1]*len(puzzle)` I clocked at `1.171e-05`. Any idea on why Counter would be slower in this instance?

Comment: 1. try `collections.Counter(puzzle).most_common(1)[0][1] == 1` 2. use [`timeit`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220801/how-to-use-timeit-module/8220943#8220943) module.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Here's how I setup my `timeit` calls: `t1 = timeit.Timer('collections.Counter(puzzle).most_common(1)[0][1] == 1', setup=setup)` and `t2 = timeit.Timer('[puzzle.count(line) for line in puzzle] == [1]*len(puzzle)', setup=setup)` where `setup` imports collections and sets an already parsed puzzle. `t1.timeit()` returns `15.0079` and `t2.timeit()` returns `4.6672`.

Comment: @tots_o_tater Depends on the size of the puzzle, Counter probably has a bigger overhead but will surely become faster than count for big enough input.

Comment: @tots_o_tater Anyhow if this taked millionths of a second it probably is not the bottleneck.

Comment: @Caridorc That makes sense. It might be part of the bottleneck since after a partial solve for the 12x12 puzzle, there are still 2177280 potential solutions. Cutting down on that should be helpful. A simple method that seems consistently faster is simply doing `len(set(puzzle)) == len(puzzle)`

Comment: @tots_o_tater Wow, I did not imagine it run so many times, so yes, go with your `set` idea and report if you notice an overall speed-up.

Comment: Also you should do away with variables in `satisfy_costraint` to fully take advantage of `all` lazyness (vars force evaluation). Again not tested (I can only use  mobile in these days)  please report any speed-ups you may get.

Comment: And square brackets create a list that is immediately discarded, remove those

Comment: I formalised my comments in an answer as it is best practice (comments may be deleted anytime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Optimization of `satisfy_costraints`

As you stated that this function runs over 2 million times, I will focus on improving its runtime.

I suggest you remove all the variables it contains as assigning a result to a var forces evaluation while avoiding it allows to take advantage of the lazyness of `all` (it stops at the first false).

Also running list.count (linear) for each item in the list (linear) is quadratic (linear x linear) I suggest you use your own `set` idea that is linear.

Square brackets create a list that is immediately discarded, you should use round ones instead to create a generator (no space / time waste).

#### "Pythonic" style

#### `range(len`

```
for i in range(len(puzzle)):
    puzzle[i] = replace_twos(puzzle[i]) 
    puzzle[i] = half_filled(puzzle[i])
```

As a general rule `range(len` means that you are fighting against the language. You can write this without explicit indexing with either list comprehension or `map` (I suggest list comprehension).

In another example:

```
for i in range(len(puzzle)):
    ....
    if like_original(puzzle[i], line)
```

You can iterate directly over the puzzle with for:

```
 for x in puzzle:
    ....
    if like_original(x, line)
```

It is clearer and you may chose any descriptive name over `x` to further improve.

#### Dry

```
line = line.replace('.00.', '1001') 
line = line.replace('00.', '001')
# .... Many more similar lines
```

Too much repetition. The DRY principle suggests a loop where only the pairs of string change:

```
for to_replace, replacement in ( ('.00.', '1001'), ...):
    line = line.replace(to_replace, replacement)
```

This improves the signal / noise ratio.

#### Proper handling of failure

```
print("UH OH")
```

Is not a proper way to handle errors.

You should raise an appropriate exception (even a costum one if that makes your code more descriptive) with a clear error message.

Something like:

```
 raise ImpossiblePuzzleException("Puzzle could not be solved")
```

Or `SolvingFailureException`.

Do not let improper end conditions slip through, fail loudly (the caller can catch the exception but he cannot avoid the print, so this also empowers the caller)

#### Use standard terminology to improve understanding

```
# Go until our solve partial returns the 
# same puzzle as before
```

Applying a function until no change is seen amymore is called finding the fixed point of that function. State that in your code for the benefit of those familiar with the fixed point concept. You may write a `fixed_point` function to abstract more.

#### Avoid making a long list that is immediately trown away

```
filled_puzzles = list(itertools.product(*line_solutions))
```

You then iterate over `filled_puzzles`. But iteration does not need a list, being `Iterable` is sufficient (duck typing, it's all about supplying the right methods, you treat object by what they can do, not what they are). Remove `list` for a free speed-up.

#### `bool`

You do a pair of times:

```
return True if x else False
```

That is equivalent to:

```
return bool(x)
```

That is just simpler.

#### `not`

```
 if x: return False
 return True
```

You do this while `return not x` would be simpler.

Comment: Good advice all around. Especially my improper error handling skills. I unaware that you could return a bool if an object existed by `bool(x)`--for the regex, I did that since it returned `None` if the match wasn't found.

Answer (score 2):

## Modifying your puzzle

In `solve_partial` you’re doing two kind of modifications:

- update `puzzle` in place by adding ones and zeroes where possible;
- create new `puzzle`s by rotating them.

Since you are already creating new lists for you puzzle, you should make it so at each stage, that way you won't have to `copy` the old puzzle in your main loop:

```
def solve_partial(puzzle):
    """
    Finds rows and columns that match a 
    criteria and replaces them 
    """

    better_puzzle = [half_filled(replace_twos(line)) for line in puzzle]
    best_puzzle = [half_filled(replace_twos(line)) for line in rotate_right(puzzle)]
    return rotate_left(best_puzzle)
```

You can then use it like:

```
puzzle_copy = []
# Go until our solve partial returns the
# same puzzle as before; this means we
# can't get any more easy placements
while puzzle != puzzle_copy:
    puzzle_copy = puzzle
    puzzle = solve_partial(puzzle)
```

and remove the need for `import copy`.

## Rotations

```
a b c d e                        e j o t y                       a b c d e
f g h i j                        d i n s x                       f g h i j
k l m n o   -- rotate_right ->   c h m r w   -- rotate_left ->   k l m n o
p q r s t                        b g l q v                       p q r s t
u v w x y                        a f k p u                       u v w x y
```

Using `[::-1]` you effectively make the grid physically rotate. But you don't really need that, since all your operations are on lines, you don't care about their ordering. By using:

```
def rotate(puzzle):
    return [''.join(t) for t in zip(*puzzle)]
```

you simplify both the writting and the runtime (since you don't have to create an intermediary list for the reverse), which will save you time since you rotate on each of your 2 millions iterations.

Puzzle will look like:

```
a b c d e                  a f k p u                  a b c d e
f g h i j                  b g l q v                  f g h i j
k l m n o   -- rotate ->   c h m r w   -- rotate ->   k l m n o
p q r s t                  d i n s x                  p q r s t
u v w x y                  e j o t y                  u v w x y
```

## `satisfy_constraints`

You can remove `contain_dot` from this as it is included in the next check (meaning if a line contains dot, then either the count of ones or the count of zeroes won't be equal to half the length of the line). And you will see that you are performing the same operations twice: one on the original puzzle and one on the rotated one. You can simplify the writing by performing these operations only once:

```
def satisfy_constraints(puzzle):
    """
    Checks a bunch of criteria the puzzle must
    match before it satisfies the constraints.
    """

    if any(not equal_num(line) for line in puzzle):
        return False
    # Make sure all of the rows/columns are unique
    if any(puzzle.count(line) != 1 for line in puzzle):
        return False
    # If any of them have three consecutive
    if any(re.search('[0]{3,}|[1]{3,}', line) for line in puzzle):
        return False

    return True
```

This assume `equal_num` is slightly modified to check if the number of ones and zeroes is exactly half the length of the line:

```
def equal_num(line):
    return line.count('1') == len(line) // 2 == line.count('0')
```

And you use `satisfy_constraint` like:

```
for p in itertools.product(*line_solutions):
    if satisfy_constraints(p) and satisfy_constraints(rotate(p)):
        return p
```

This lets you short-circuit before rotating the puzzle which can save you some time too.

You also don't need to use a `set` to build `line_solutions` since you already used a `set` in `get_permutations`:

```
line_solutions = [
    [line for line in valid_lines if re.match(partial, line)]
    for partial in puzzle
]
```

You may also have noticed that I used `re` directly in the code rather than in their own functions: since these functions were used at only one place, this reduce the overhead of calling them.

## Building the search space

Since you seem to be using Python 3, you can use the `yield from` construct to avoid relying on `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
MATCH = {
    '00': ['10', '11'],
    '01': ['01', '10', '00'],
    '10': ['01', '10', '11'],
    '11': ['00', '01'],
    '': ['00', '01', '10', '11'],
}

def build_perms(prefix, left, accumulator=''):
    """
    A recursive function that takes an original
    prefix, a dictionary that matches with the
    prefix, and the number of iterations we have
    left. Returns all the permutations for a prefix.
    """
    grown = accumulator + prefix
    remaining = left - len(prefix)
    if remaining < 1:
        yield grown
    else:
        for postfix in MATCH[prefix]:
            yield from build_perms(postfix, remaining, grown)


def get_permutations(size):
    return list(filter(equal_num, build_perms('', size)))
```

I also extracted `MATCH` as a constant as it never changes whatever the size of the puzzle is.

## Managing files

> ```
> puzzle = open('puzzle.txt', 'r').readlines()
> puzzle = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in puzzle]
> ```

You `open` the puzzle file but never `close` it. To avoid that, it is good practice to always use `open` in conjunction with `with`. You should also use `strip` instead of replacing newlines with `replace`. You can also use `splitlines` on the whole file:

```
with open('puzzle.txt') as takuzu:
    puzzle = takuzu.read().splitlines()
```

or

```
with open('puzzle.txt') as takuzu:
    puzzle = [line.strip() for line in takuzu]
```

Comment: Very thorough answer! I'll address it in more detail when I get a chance. Much appreciated.

Comment: I avoided a method like `puzzle_copy = puzzle` since I assumed the references from a new assignment would be copied over to `puzzle_copy`, but this appears to not be the case. For **Rotations**, I thought keeping the original order mattered, but this also does not appear to be the case. The updates for `satisfy_constraints` also make sense. For `build_perms`, I saw yield but avoided it in hopes the program would be backwards compatible with 2.7.11; although a clean solution, is there an alternative? Using `with` for managing files seems clean. Thanks again for the great write-up!

Comment: You can change `yield from <whatever>` into `for element in <whatever>: yield element` for backward compatibility. It's syntactic sugar: see [there](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/).

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion would be to change fill rest to go square by square. If you instead use a dancing link solution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links), you may find a pretty big speedup. Basically the advantage is that you can often find that a solution won't work without completing the rest of the board.

Comment: The algorithm looks applicable to the problem--I'll look into it more. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I recently used it for a sudoku solver.